# What problems would arise in physics by treating infinitesimals as ~1 (in units much smaller than the measurement precision) rather than ~0?

Tags: differentiation, calculus, approximations

I have a hopefully simple/ignorant question.

The difference quotient, where $h$ is an "infinitesimally" small value:
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

What problems (if any) would arise by thinking of this as $h \approx 1$, in units where $x >> 1$ and $f(x) >> 1$?

I am asking here rather than the mathematics stack exchange because I am concerned only with cases when there is finite precision in the measurements.

Comment: The derivative is defined for $h\to 0$. You can approximate it with $g_f(x,h):= (f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ such that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} g_f(x,h) = f^\prime(x)$. The quality of this approximation obviously depends on $f$ as well as on $h$.

Answer (score 3):

It would require you to tediously carry around an unknown parameter *h* in your expressions. This would complicate symbolic math without any advantage.

But note that this is essentially what we do in numerical methods.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the approximation of the 1 dropping out (for the same reason of being a very small value) still work as long as the other values are much larger? I also agree that numerical integration does this to the extent it is practical.

Comment: @Livid Sure, but how do you decide when to drop terms? That's what calculus gives you: terms which converge to zero in the limit are dropped. If they're always finite, you make it harder.

Comment: @Livid This is a physics group. What physical insight do you see in your mathematical approach?

Comment: I was thinking about how Newton was criticized for "ghosts of departed quantities" because the $dx$ in $f'(x) = dy/dx$ was not dropped. If $dx \approx 1$, then that problem goes away. Then I wondered if this would cause any problems in physics. Whether or not the universe is continuous vs discrete, measurements have always been finite. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to know what it means $h\to0$ and find the relevant scale to which you want to compare it to. The natural approach you had is $x$, except it isn't quite correct. The simplest way to see this is by expanding it to next order to estimate the error:
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)+\frac{f''(x)h}{2} +o(h)
$$

so the relevant scale is rather:
$$h \ll \frac{2f'(x)}{f''(x)}$$
Intuitively, this translates the idea that the local behaviour of $f$ is crucial to estimate the speed of convergence. As you can see, if you're interested in relative error, the scale of $f$ is irrelevant, so your condition $f(x)\gg1$ is not necessary. Also, you can see that it isn't $x$ which will directly determine the relevant scale. Naturally, for a sufficiently large difference $h\ll x$ you'll necessarily arrive at the point where the above criterion is also verified.

To come back to your approach, you'd rather need to choose a system of units where $h\sim 1$ and $\frac{2f'(x)}{f''(x)}\gg1$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very interesting. Seems I need to learn more... But can you share any consequences of treating the problem in this way? Eg, now there is a role of the second derivative when choosing h ~ 1, which would be irrelevant if h ~0.

Comment: I don't quit understand "which would be irrelevant if $h\sim0$" Once again, when taking the limit to $0$, there is no absolute size, so it would be still relevant as it is the reference scale. An important consequence is the necessary assumption that $f$ is $\mathcal C^2$ to estimate the error. However, for typical noisy data, this is not true, which shows that this method won't work. What you would typically do is do a regression over many points, which is redundant in the deterministic case. Check out for example the Savitzky–Golay filter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky–Golay_filter

Comment: If $h \approx 1$ then (according to your answer) we are justified in dropping $h$ when $2f'(x) >> f"(x)$. If $h \approx 0$ then I would think that is the case for $2f'(x) >> 0$. Perhaps that is wrong.

Comment: Once again, there is no such thing as absolute size. Therefore, $h\sim0$ is meaningless, you need a reference scale to compare it to and $\gg0$ is even more meaningless because that’s the case for every non $0$ number

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I understand from your answer/comments that the practical meaning of infinitesimal depends on the behaviour of the function where it is being measured. This makes sense to me and I hope that is correct. But then you provided an equation at the end of your answer, and when I manipulated it according to standard rules of algebra to attempt drawing a conclusion you said that does not make sense. So clearly I am missing something, perhaps you can expand on the answer. I am likely missing some background knowledge required to understand.

Comment: No problem, is it the Landau’s $o$ notation? You can ignore it for now. I first Taylor expanded the ratio to get the first equation. Using $f’(x)\gg f’’(x)h/2$ which means that the error is negligible compared to the final result, I found the next equation just by dividing (note that there are some caveats, I’m assuming it’s twice derivable and the second derivative is non $0$, but the reasoning can be generalized to other cases).

Comment: My problem is more with "Therefore, $h∼0$ is meaningless". Do you also mean that $h∼1$ is meaningless? Ie, without context any value would be meaningless.

Comment: The problem is $\sim 0$. You can talk about $\to0$, but $\sim$ usually means order order of magnitude, the exact mathematical definition is asymptotic equivalence.  $0$ has no order of magnitude, so this is why I'm saying it's meaningless. $\sim$ is typically used to say how fast something goes to $0$ or $\infty$.

Comment: thanks again. I am obviously not using the notation in the correct way then. Obviously I am having difficulty communicating because of this, and also assume I am totally off-track anyway. If you are willing to continue humouring me, can you offer a response to my comment to JohnDoty with regards to "ghosts of departed quantities"?

Comment: I don’t think it’s an issue anymore since there is now a rigorous definition for limits thanks to Weierstrass. Note that there is are many results similar to calculus without taking the limit, check out finite difference and umbral calculus. In general, taking the limit isn’t necessarily more physically relevant, but rather more convenient for pencil and paper calculations and capturing qualitative behavior.